# Rhomobile: No params being posted from form

Tags: ruby, rhomobile, rhodes

I have a simple form that I want to use to search surnames:

```
<form method="POST" action="<%= url_for :action => :index %>">
  <label for="surname" class="itemLabel">Search Surname</label>
  <input type="text" id="surname" name="surname" class="" <%= placeholder("Surname") %> />
  <input type="submit" value="Search"/>
</form>
```

In the controller index method I have the following code:

```
def index   
    if @params['surname'].nil? or @params['surname'].empty?
      @fencers = Fencer.find(:all) 
    else
      @fencers = Fencer.find(:all, :conditions => {:surname => @params['surname']})
    end
    render :back => '/app'
end
```

If it has a surname param then it searches, if not it will just display all available. When I debug this action I never see any params when it gets called after posting the search form.

This search form is based on the auto-generated login form (which works) so I'm a bit confused. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try posting to different action within your controller, or rename your index action to something like [model]_index.

Rhodes seems to like to mess around with query parameters passed to the index action.

I ran a quick test using your code and if you change the controller method to "index_new", the arguments are passed successfully.